# Use one property name with multiple constructors that take different types

Tags: c#, reflection, tcp, constructor

I have a class that has several constructors like this:

```
var Value; //Does not work

    public MyClass(int val, byte[] data)
    {
        //Assign Value 
    }

    public MyClass(short val, byte[] data)
    {
        //Assign Value 
    }

    public MyClass(bool val, byte[]data)
    {
        //Assign Value 
    }
    //......More down
```

Is it possible to create a Property called Value of the same type as the parameters passed in the constructors?  The reason is that i am passing a byte[] coming from a TCP Stream and i need to know the type so i know what Bitconverter function to call.

The alternative I was thinking was to have the caller pass an enum with the type in the constructor as well

Comment: You could if you made the class generic.

Comment: This is what [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) are for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that `var` does not mean generic or loosely typed.  It is simply syntactic sugar that infers a type based on the value you provide.

However all is not lost, C# has a feature called [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) that will allow you to define a type when you instantiate the class allowing you to have a single class that could can handle multiple "types" in some way.  Using generics should give you the result you want.

First thing you need to do is make your class generic:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public MyClass(T initialValue)
    {
        Value = initialValue;
    }

    public T Value {get; set;}
}
```

Then you can create instances of your class like this:

```
var myObj = new MyClass<bool>(true); // "myObj.Value" is a bool
var myObj2 = new MyClass<int>(13); // "myObj2.Value" is an int
```

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9L7QVp)